# IIS redirect subfolder to another website

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config

I have a simple situation, but none of the results that I have found here did not help. I have a WCF project, hosted on IIS as a web site, let's say it is www.myproject.com, I want to configure a URL rewrite for www.myproject.com/1b to point on www.myproject2.com but have the same URL, what is the correct way to do it via web.config of "myproject"?

Answer (score 0):

If `www.myproject2.com` is on a different server, you will have to write code to proxy from one to the other.  If not, it's possible by configuring `1b` as an application underneath the application for `www.myproject.com`.  That's not something that can be done in the web.config. It requires additional IIS settings, and the real trick is getting the web.configs to play nice with each other, as the default way it works is that you end up with hierarchical web.configs where some settings are inherited and some conflict.

Comment: they are both on the same server, are you sure there is no way to end up with web.config change only?

Comment: I suppose it depends on exactly what you mean by 'point to'.  If you're talking about a redirect, that can be done in the web.config.  I assumed you wanted the URL in the browser to remain at `www.myproject.com/1b`, in which case I'm fairly certain you can't do that just with the web.config.  I'd love to be proven wrong, actually, as I have a similar problem with several sites with a million+ users.

Comment: Are they on the same server?